# Java graphics behaving strange

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm making a program in which you can click on a JLabel which holds an image and
circles will appear on the JLabel. This works flawless on my macintosh/java6 but when I'm
using windows/java7 all sorts of weird things happens. On some parts of the image you can't
draw a circle. It's like an invisible square in the middle of the picture. And sometimes the
circles disappear and come back at different times.
Everytime i draw a new circle all the circles are getting redrawn on top of the label.

```
public void paint(JComponent label) {
    Graphics g = label.getGraphics();
    for (T node : nodes.keySet()) {
        Point p = nodes.get(node);
        Color color;
        if (p.selected) {
            color = Color.RED;
        } else {
            color = Color.BLUE;
        }
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 20, 20));
        g.drawString((String) node, p.x, p.y);
    }       
}
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Use `public void paintComponent(final Graphics g)`. You have to override it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You'll want to read the tutorials before doing graphics programming as it requires throwing out some old assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use getGraphics(), it can return null and at best is a snap shot of the last paint cycle

As soon as a repaint occurs anything painted to it will be removed

Instead, as Legend has already suggested, create yourself a custom label and override paintComponent and perform your painting here

Remember, painting is stateless, this means that on each repaint, you'll have to reconstruct your state

Take a look at [Custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your paint(JComponent j); method and try using the following JLabel.
Tweak as necessary to suit your needs.

```
final JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("!X!") {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (T node : nodes.keySet()) {
            Point p = nodes.get(node);
            Color color;
            if (p.selected) {
                color = Color.RED;
            } else {
                color = Color.BLUE;
            }
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", 20, 20));
            g.drawString((String) node, p.x, p.y);
        }              
    }
};
```

Comment: Spruced that up a bit for you. The `paintComponent` method is empty in the super class, calling that method would have no effect. Also, you still included the `Graphics g = jlabel.getGraphics()` portion.

Comment: @Legend I'm confused at you suggestion that `super.paintComponent` is empty/has no effect.  It's responsible for preparing the Graphics context for painting, and in the case of `JLabel` this is very important as it's transparent. Failure to do so could cause nasty paint artifacts...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree - I left it in but removed getGraphics() call.